# AWK: Concatenate matching pattern with a field separator

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

**Input File:**

```
cat /tmp/filename

app_name="MysqlCluster"
whatever whatever
whatever whatever
whatever whatever
whatever whatever
region="Europe"
```

**Expected output:**

```
MysqlCluster_Europe
```

**Attempts:**

```
root@localhost:~# awk -F\" '/app_name|region/ {printf "%s_", $2}' /tmp/filename
MysqlCluster_Europe_root@localhost:~# 

root@localhost:~# awk -F\" '/app_name|region/ {OFS="_"; printf "%s", $2}' /tmp/filename
MysqlClusterEuroperoot@localhost:~#

root@localhost:~# awk -F\" '/app_name|region/ {printf "%s_", $2} END{print} ' /tmp/filename
MysqlCluster_Europe_

And few other attempts on similar lines but have not been successful.
```

**I am looking for:**

```
root@localhost:~# awk <here goes some awk magic> /tmp/filename
MysqlCluster_Europe    <<< NOTE: No Underscore at the end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following will work for your example. (It will not print a line feed though.)

```
awk -F\" '/^(app_name|region)/ { printf "%s%s", s, $2; s="_" }' /tmp/filename
```

Not to diminish your effort at all but handling `app_name` and `region` in two separate actions would be more practical imo, this way it will support multiple app_name-region pairs as well.

```
awk -F\" '/^app_name/ { printf "%s_", $2 } /^region/ { print $2 }' /tmp/filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk. This should work even if you have more app_name-region pairs in file(s):

```
$ awk '
/^(app_name|region)=/ {                     # look for matching records
    a[++c][1]                               # initialize 2d array 
    split($0,a[c],"\"")                     # split on quote
}
END {                                       # after processing file(s)
    for(i=1;i in a;i++)                     # loop all stored values
        printf "%s%s",a[i][2],(i%2?"_":ORS) # output
}' file
MysqlCluster_Europe
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is with a regex to match the app_name and region in column1 and then split by the "=" character.

```
awk '$1 ~ "app_name|region" {split($0,a,"="); printf a[2]}' /tmp/filename | sed 's/"//g'
```

sed removes the double quotes.

BR

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'=?"' '{f[$1]=$2} $1=="region"{print f["app_name"] "_" $2}' file
MysqlCluster_Europe
```